# Compute the following limits: $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n !}{d(n !) \cdot \phi(n !)} \& \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n !}{2^{d(n !)}}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

For each positive integer $m$, we have that $d(m)$ is the number of positive divisors of $m$; also, we let $\phi(m)$ be the corresponding value of the Euler- $\phi$ function. Then compute the following limits:
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n !}{d(n !) \cdot \phi(n !)} \&
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n !}{2^{d(n !)}}
$$

I think the first one is either $1$ or $0$, and the second is $\infty$.
I tried to write the factorization of $n!$ and write $d(n!)$ and $\phi(n!)$ with the primes factorization so that something would be canceled with one another, but I could not proceed after that.

Comment: Do you know the asymptotic properties of these functions?

Comment: I think I have seen them.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give them another try; I think the following answer might be true:

For the first one:
If $n! = 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$ then:
$$
d(n!)=(a_1+1)...(a_k+1) \\
\phi(n!) = n! (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})...(1-\frac{1}{p_k})
$$
So the limit will be:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)\cdot n! (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})...(1-\frac{1}{p_k})}
\\ =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)\cdot (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})...(1-\frac{1}{p_k})}
$$
Since every $a_i$ is at least $1$, then $a_i+1 \geq 2$, so $\frac{1}{a_i+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, we will have the following:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)\cdot (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})...(1-\frac{1}{p_k})} \\  \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2^k \cdot (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})...(1-\frac{1}{p_k})}
$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$ $p_i$ will be bigger and therefore, $1-\frac{1}{p_i} \rightarrow 1$ and therefore, this  product $\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-\frac{1}{p_i})$ will be going to $1$. As the number of divisors increases as $n \rightarrow \infty$ increases, so $2^k \rightarrow \infty$, the limit will be $0$.

For the second one: If $n! = 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$ then: $d(n!)=(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)$.So we will have:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{2^{(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)}} \\
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{a_1}3^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}}{2^{(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)}}\\
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{2}{2})^{a_1}(\frac{3}{2})^{a_2}...(\frac{p_k}{2})^{a_k}\cdot \frac{1}{2^k}
$$
We know that for $p=11 \Rightarrow(\frac{11}{2})^{a_3}\geq (\frac{8}{2})^{a_5}=4^{a_5}$, So we have the following:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{2}{2})^{a_1}(\frac{3}{2})^{a_2}...(\frac{p_k}{2})^{a_k}\cdot \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{4^{a_5+a_6+...+a_k}}{2^k} \geq \frac{2^{2(a_5+a_6+...+a_k)}}{2^k} = 2^{2(a_5+a_6+...+a_k)-k}
$$
Since $a_i$ growth is bigger than $k$, I believe this limit goes to $\infty$.

Comment: The first solution is a valid strategy, although some details should be filled in rather than unconcretely asserting "this will get bigger". In the second solution, the second equality is incorrect: in the denominator, $2^{(a_1+1)\cdots(a_k+1)}$ is not equal to $2^{a_1}\cdots 2^{a_k}+k$.